# Does php mail need configuration to work?

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to do a very simple mail form in PHP but get the error:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index:   in /var/www/html/sites/send_contact.php on line 10, referer: http://example.com/contact2.php

My PHP file looks like this:

```
<?php // send_contact.php
// Contact subject
$subject =$_POST["$subject"]; 
// Details
$message=$_POST["$detail"];

// Mail of sender
$mail_from=$_POST["$customer_mail"]; 
// From 
$name2=$_POST["$name2"];

$header="From: $mail_from\r\n";

// Enter your email address
$to="joe@mail.com";

$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

// Check, if message sent to your email 
// display message "We've recived your information"
if($send_contact){
echo "We've recived your contact information";
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

Comment: If your field is named subject, then you would type $_POST["subject"] .  If you want the value in $_POST that has a key stored in $subject, use $_POST[$subject] .

Comment: Just in case: once this problem is solved, be sure to do some input scrubbing before putting this into production...
http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/ian_gilfillan20060412.php3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest guess is that you're doing a mistake accessing your variables.

instead of:

```
$name2=$_POST["$name2"];
```

use this:

```
$name2=$_POST["name2"];
```

Or, if you know the difference and are doing this on purpose, make sure your `$name2` variable is defined with the correct name of the HTML form field.

As an aside, I would strongly recommend using a library like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) to send emails.
Your example is quite simple and the mail() should work just fine, but for anything more elaborate (ie. having attachments or html) or needing to send using an external mail server by SMTP (with or without authentication), it will do a much better job and save you lots of time.

For a better idea, check [this example](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=exampleasmtp) from their website:

```
require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on     errors, which we need to catch

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP

try {
  $mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
  $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
  $mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // sets the SMTP server
  $mail->Port       = 26;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
  $mail->Username   = "yourname@yourdomain"; // SMTP account username
  $mail->Password   = "yourpassword";        // SMTP account password
  $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->AddAddress('whoto@otherdomain.com', 'John Doe');
  $mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), advanced';
  $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';     // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
  $mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'));
  $mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer.gif');      // attachment
  $mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.gif'); // attachment
  $mail->Send();
  echo "Message Sent OK<p></p>\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you exactly what is wrong:

Line 10:

```
$name2=$_POST["$name2"];
```

You are using '$name2' before it is defined.

PHP can substitute variables in strings:

```
$var1 = "bar";
echo "foo $var1"; // prints "foo bar"
```

In your HTML use something similar to the following:

```
<input type="...whatever..." name="name2" />
```

Then in PHP, assuming the data was POSTed, you would access it using:

```
$name2 = $_POST["name2"];
```

Comment: that's exactly what i did , my $name2 = $_POST["name2"]; declaration is exactly the same as what you put.

Comment: In that case, your HTML hasn't got any field named "name2", or, at least, it's not posting with your form.  Otherwise the POST superglobal would have a name2 key and you'd get no error. Is your page live?  A link would be helpful.

Comment: yeah its up at: http://dropcollective.com/beta/dropcollective/subpages/contact2.php

Comment: maybe i don't have an smtp server setup on my system?

Comment: As the error doesn't say anything about an SMTP server, I don't think that's the problem. As Kelix and Carlos are saying, you probably made a mistake defining the index in the $_POST array.

Comment: Joe, the difference between mine and yours is that my version has no '$' in front of 'name2' in '$_POST[]'. My post above explains why this does not work to some extent. You're problem is not the mail server - I repeat - the error is clearly pointing at what is wrong in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code doesn't pass the $_POST data as you expect. I recommend you to check the keys of $_POST as follows:

```
<?php
print_r(array_keys($_POST));
?>
```

If it doesn't display the value of $name2, it means you should modify the web page sending form data to send_contact.php.